# Install Linux to a single partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, installation, bios

Good morning everyone.
Not sure if i am posting this on the right site, i am new here.
Anyway. I am trying to setup a Win 10/Linux dual boot on my computer. This is not the first time I'm doing this but still, all the grub configuration etc are too much of a hassle for me and I'm struggling to understand all of this. That's why i decided to install Linux (Ubuntu Gnome if that's a necessary information) to my data HDD whereas Win 10 is on my SSD. I will be using my BIOS boot sequence menu for selecting the boot medium (and OS). Is there anything i need to be aware of when creating such a setup? Or will a traditional installation do it?
Also, I want to install Linux to **one partition only** with the other two partitions (containing movies, music, pictures and documents) left untouched. How do i do that? Do i just select the partition, format it to ext4, set mountpoint to / and select the same partition for the bootloader installation? Or do I have to set any flags such as "boot" or something? 
Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SuperUser

If you are so unsure I would suggest to phisically attach just one drive (the future linux one) at time while installing. You could also prepare free non partitioned space on that drive with Windows if that makes you feel better :-)

Then install Linux: all of the modern graphical distributions will ask you if you want to use "free" (unpartitioned) space and they could do it for you.

It will work if you use a single mountpoint as / or the classic "many partition" style of linux. Don't forget to add some swap space. Bonus, you could play with grub on that hard drive until you get Windows recognized too. Should be easy.